Sending a request with httr2: JSON body contains a nested JSON input
In the below example i am using Google Maps Places API's (new) Text Search (new) request method. See here more information about this API method.
Basically i am starting to have problems when the JSON request body starts to have nested (and nasty) elements. Below i will give examples on what works and what doesn't work:
Works: request with string objects as inputs
library(httr2)

# Test params:
textQuery = "nature retreat in Southwest Alentejo, Portugal"
maxResultCount = 10
key = API_KEY

params <- list(textQuery = textQuery,
               maxResultCount = maxResultCount)

req <-
  request("https://places.googleapis.com/v1/places:searchText") |>
  req_headers(
    `X-Goog-Api-Key` = key,
    `X-Goog-FieldMask` = "*",
    `Content-Type` = "application/json"
  ) |>
  req_body_json(Filter(Negate(is.null), params))

req |>
  req_dry_run()
# POST /v1/places: searchText HTTP/1.1
# Host: places.googleapis.com
# User-Agent: httr2/0.2.3 r-curl/5.2.1 libcurl/7.81.0
# Accept: */*
#   Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip, br, zstd
# X-Goog-Api-Key: API_KEY
# X-Goog-FieldMask: *
#   Content-Type: application/json
# Content-Length: 47
# 
# {"textQuery":"nature retreat in Southwest Alentejo, Portugal","maxResultCount":10}

req |>
  req_perform()
# <httr2_response>
#   POST https://places.googleapis.com/v1/places:searchText
# Status: 200 OK
# Content-Type: application/json
# Body: In memory (192086 bytes)

Doesn't work: JSON object as input
Now i am trying to add a JSON input to the JSON request body. Below i am trying to reproduce this example from the Places API, which has the following curl command:
curl -X POST -d '{
  "textQuery" : "Spicy Vegetarian Food",
  "openNow": true,
  "maxResultCount": 10,
  "locationBias": {
    "circle": {
      "center": {"latitude": 37.7937, "longitude": -122.3965},
      "radius": 500.0
    }
  },
}' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'X-Goog-Api-Key: API_KEY' \
-H 'X-Goog-FieldMask: places.displayName,places.formattedAddress' \
'https://places.googleapis.com/v1/places:searchText'

This should be the httr2 equivalent, but it doesn't work:
# Test params:
textQuery = "Spicy Vegetarian Food"
openNow = "true"
maxResultCount = 10
latitude = 37.7937
longitude = -122.3965
radius = 500
key = API_KEY

# Creating the locationRestriction JSON parameter:
body <- list()
innerBody <- list()
innerInnerBody <- list()
innerInnerBody$latitude <- latitude
innerInnerBody$longitude <- longitude
innerBody$center <- innerInnerBody
innerBody$radius <- radius
body$circle <- innerBody
locationBias <- jsonlite::toJSON(body, auto_unbox = TRUE, pretty = TRUE)
locationBias
# {
#   "circle": {
#     "center": {
#       "latitude": 37.7937,
#       "longitude": -122.3965
#     },
#     "radius": 500
#   }
# } 

params <- list(textQuery = textQuery,
               openNow = openNow,
               maxResultCount = maxResultCount,
               locationBias = locationBias)
params
# $textQuery
# [1] "Spicy Vegetarian Food"
# 
# $openNow
# [1] "true"
# 
# $maxResultCount
# [1] 10
# 
# $locationBias
# {
#   "circle": {
#     "center": {
#       "latitude": 37.7937,
#       "longitude": -122.3965
#     },
#     "radius": 500
#   }
# }

req <-
  request("https://places.googleapis.com/v1/places:searchText") |>
  req_headers(
    `X-Goog-Api-Key` = key,
    `X-Goog-FieldMask` = "*",
    `Content-Type` = "application/json"
  ) |>
  req_body_json(Filter(Negate(is.null), params))

req |>
  req_dry_run()
# POST /v1/places: searchText HTTP/1.1
# Host: places.googleapis.com
# User-Agent: httr2/0.2.3 r-curl/5.2.1 libcurl/7.81.0
# Accept: */*
#   Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip, br, zstd
# X-Goog-Api-Key: API_KEY
# X-Goog-FieldMask: *
#   Content-Type: application/json
# Content-Length: 228
# 
# {"textQuery":"Spicy Vegetarian Food","openNow":"true","maxResultCount":10,"locationBias":"{\n  \"circle\": {\n    \"center\": {\n      \"latitude\": 37.7937,\n      \"longitude\": -122.3965\n    },\n    \"radius\": 500\n  }\n}"}

req |>
  req_perform()
# Error in `req_perform()`:
#   ! HTTP 400 Bad Request.

I have double checked that by removing the locationBias input all works fine. Any ideas why i get the 400 error in httr2 with the JSON locationBias input?

Note that maxResultCount was deprecated by the Places API in May 2024, it is now pageSize.

According to curl example, payload is a regular JSON object; as you are passing body through jsonlite::toJSON() and then assign it to locationBias, it becomes a string. Note how it gets escaped in req_dry_run() output:
# ... "locationBias":"{\n  \"circle\": {\n    \"center\": {\n      \"latitude\": 37.7937,\n      \"longitude\": -122.3965\n    },\n    \"radius\": 500\n  }\n}"}


Without jsonlite::toJSON() it should be fine:
library(httr2)

# Test params:
textQuery = "Spicy Vegetarian Food"
openNow = "true"
maxResultCount = 10
latitude = 37.7937
longitude = -122.3965
radius = 500
key = "API_KEY"

# Creating the locationRestriction JSON parameter:
body <- list()
innerBody <- list()
innerInnerBody <- list()
innerInnerBody$latitude <- latitude
innerInnerBody$longitude <- longitude
innerBody$center <- innerInnerBody
innerBody$radius <- radius
body$circle <- innerBody
str(body)
#> List of 1
#>  $ circle:List of 2
#>   ..$ center:List of 2
#>   .. ..$ latitude : num 37.8
#>   .. ..$ longitude: num -122
#>   ..$ radius: num 500

params <- list(textQuery = textQuery,
               openNow = openNow,
               maxResultCount = maxResultCount,
               locationBias = body)
str(params)
#> List of 4
#>  $ textQuery     : chr "Spicy Vegetarian Food"
#>  $ openNow       : chr "true"
#>  $ maxResultCount: num 10
#>  $ locationBias  :List of 1
#>   ..$ circle:List of 2
#>   .. ..$ center:List of 2
#>   .. .. ..$ latitude : num 37.8
#>   .. .. ..$ longitude: num -122
#>   .. ..$ radius: num 500

req <-
  request("https://places.googleapis.com/v1/places:searchText") |>
  req_headers(
    `X-Goog-Api-Key` = key,
    `X-Goog-FieldMask` = "*",
    `Content-Type` = "application/json"
  ) |>
  req_body_json(Filter(Negate(is.null), params))

Payload in request looks fine now:
req |>
  req_dry_run()
#> POST /v1/places: searchText HTTP/1.1
#> Host: places.googleapis.com
#> User-Agent: httr2/1.0.0 r-curl/5.2.1 libcurl/8.3.0
#> Accept: */*
#> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
#> X-Goog-Api-Key: API_KEY
#> X-Goog-FieldMask: *
#> Content-Type: application/json
#> Content-Length: 178
#> 
#> {"textQuery":"Spicy Vegetarian Food","openNow":"true","maxResultCount":10,"locationBias":{"circle":{"center":{"latitude":37.793700000000001,"longitude":-122.3965},"radius":500}}}

Created on 2024-04-24 with reprex v2.1.0

Your are right, i  didn't notice the "string-fication" (not to use another term:-) of the locationBias input. By removing the jsonlite::toJSON() step and assigning directly locationBias = body as you show above, i confirm that i get no errors. Thanks for posting you answer!
